# How can I use a macro When I have Multiple Excel windows open with out getting File in Use?

Tags: vba, excel

After I open the first excel window I keep getting [this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdkir.png) below.

[image: read-only]

Is there any way I can avoid this? I know the reason is because it can't get the write permission but I need to be able to use a macro across multiple excel files that I have open at the same time. I need to have more than 1 excel file open as it is work.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't open the files in the same instance of Excel? Currently it sounds like you're creating a new instance of Excel for each file you open.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep multiple files open in the workbooks collection, use it instead of window, or you could just disable notifications.. (http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/disable-alert-warning-messages.shtml)

Comment: I don't want to disable the alert that reminds me to save if I haven't already saved. Is there a way to disable specific alerts or turn them back on after a file has opened and disable before closing?

Comment: Hi, sure, you just toggle it, so depending on your code just place the switch at or around the events you don't want to see alerts for.
For instance (straight from excel developer reference)
`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`
`Workbooks("BOOK1.XLS").Close`
`Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'In order to bypass the clipboard prompt

Workbooks.Open filename:=PERSONAL.XLS, notify:=True
```

Comment: Did this help you?